# Bad words detection on username

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, yup

I need to detect bad words in a username and for now I m just using regEX to validate it on a certain pattern like that :

```
"/^[A-Za-z0-9]*(\d*\.\d*)*[A-Za-z0-9]+$/"
```

which means is "Usernames may contain letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) and full stops (.)" i am using Yup and formik for the form and validation

Comment: Remember to pay attention to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem :)

Comment: This is more complicated than you think. Bad words in what language? Hui is a Russian swear word, but a very common Chinese name. There exist real people whose last name is Fuck. I'd say don't bother: or let people complain and decide on a case by case basis. If you must, offload it: find some dictionary of bad words and check against it. But beter off, don't bother.

Comment: A good read on this topic: https://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it, AFAIK, would be to maintain a list of disallowed words, and when validating username, loop through those and check if the username contains any of them.

You can potentially do it only when you're registering a user into the system for performance reasons.

You can use regex but I think it would be overkill.

Comment: I had the same idea but i was just looking if there isn't a more optimal solution